# A false reasoning for a better intuition behind the universal coefficient theorem

Tags: homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space. I am trying to understand the natural homomorphism
$$H^*(M,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^*(M,\mathbb{R}),$$
induced by the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

The universal coefficient theorem says that this homomorphism may not be injective, namely when torsion elements exist. I am trying to understand this in a very elementary way, and to that aim I have written a **false argument of injectivity**. I would like to understand where this argument fails, so I could have more intuition behind this non-injectivity. Any help would be appreciated.

Denote $C_k(M)$ the free abelian group generated by $k$-singular chains on $M$, and by:
$$C^k(M,\mathbb{Z}) := Hom(C_k(M),\mathbb{Z}), \quad  C^k(M,\mathbb{R}) := Hom(C_k(M),\mathbb{R}).$$
Then the boundary operator $\partial$ on $C_k(M)$ dualizes to boundary operators $\delta_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\delta_{\mathbb{R}}$ on the two above groups respectively.

Let

$$Z^k_{\mathbb{Z}} := ker(\delta_{\mathbb{Z}} : C^k(M,\mathbb{Z}) \to C^{k+1}(M,\mathbb{Z})), \quad Z^k_{\mathbb{R}} := ker(\delta_{\mathbb{R}} : C^k(M,\mathbb{R}) \to C^{k+1}(M,\mathbb{R})),$$
and 
$$B^k_{\mathbb{Z}} := im(\delta_{\mathbb{Z}} : C^{k-1}(M,\mathbb{Z}) \to C^k(M,\mathbb{Z})), \quad  B^k_{\mathbb{R}} := im(\delta_{\mathbb{R}} : C^{k-1}(M,\mathbb{R}) \to C^k(M,\mathbb{R})).$$

1. Since $Hom(M,-)$ is left exact, the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ yields an injection $C^k(M,\mathbb{Z}) \hookrightarrow C^k(M,\mathbb{R})$.
2. Since $\delta_{\mathbb{R} | C^k(M,\mathbb{Z})} = \delta_{\mathbb{Z}}$, we have inclusions
   $$B^k_{\mathbb{Z}} \subset B^k_{\mathbb{R}}, \quad Z^k_{\mathbb{Z}} \subset Z^k_{\mathbb{R}},$$
   which yield a natural homomorphism $\rho : H^k(M,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^k(M,\mathbb{R})$ in cohomology.

Suppose that $\alpha \in Z^k_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ is such that $\rho([\alpha]) = 0$. This means that $\alpha \in B^k_{\mathbb{R}}$. But $\alpha \in C^k(M,\mathbb{Z})$, so $\alpha \in B^k_{\mathbb{R}} \cap C^k(M,\mathbb{Z}) = B^k_{\mathbb{Z}}$, and therefore $[\alpha] = 0$.

Could someone tell me where this reasoning fails ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The error is at the end: the intersection of real boundaries and integral chains is not equal to the integral boundaries.

For instance if you consider a chain complex $\mathbb Z \overset{2}\to \mathbb Z$ and change coefficients to $\mathbb R$ then in <s>degree 0</s> degree 1 one has $B^1_{\mathbb R} \cap C^1_{\mathbb Z} = \mathbb Z$ but $B^1_{\mathbb Z} = 2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you extend your comment ? What would be the "difference" between these two sets ?

Comment: @BrianT I added an example - maybe that helps? If it’s not clear please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So if I understand well, you identify $\mathbb{Z} =C^{-1}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathbb{Z} = C^0(M,\mathbb{Z})$ ? Do you have an intuition of why these sets are different ?

Comment: Basically if you rescale a linear map over the integers, it shrinks the image. But if you then pass to the rationals/reals, now division is possible and all rescalings must have the same image. So if you intersect them with the integer values, they all get the same set - ignoring the shrinking image. So, you can’t determine the integer boundaries from the rational/real boundaries alone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @BrianT Sorry I edited the labeling to 0,1. I don’t wish to identify the two groups in any way, but since this problem is purley homological algebra (UCT is a theorem about chain complexes) and not topology, I didn’t see a use for any extra notation.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I'm trying to understand better what changes when taking cohomology with different types of coefficients (say integers and real coefficients). It seems that cohomology with integer coefficients provide more subtle information that with real coefficients. Am I in the wrong intuition saying that ? Do you have a reference where I can find more information about this ?

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @BrianT integer coefficients is the most general. At least for complexes of finitely generated groups you can immediately predict from integer coefficients the cohomology with coefficients mod $p$ over the rationals/reals. Over the rationals, you just kill the torsion. Over mod $p$ the $p$-torsion stays but also gets copied into the previous degree as well. (Try some examples.)

Comment: What do you mean by coefficients $mod \ p$ over the rationals/reals ?

Comment: So cohomology with integral coefficients will tell me what type of torsion I have, say $p$-torsion. Then taking cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z} /p \mathbb{Z}$ will give me all the possible information I could want regarding this torsion, and taking coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ or another field of characteristic different than $p$ will erase this information ?

Comment: @BrianT Integral cohomology tells you everything including al the torsion, characteristic 0 tells you about nontorsion, mod p tells you only about nontorsion and $p$-torsion.